# Include global sass with Angular 4 and webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, sass

I have a project built on Angular 4 with webpack with HMR.  Not sure if this matters but I am using the ASP Core 2 with angular template.

What I am trying to do is have a global/main scss file that is applied across all components.  I wanted to have this scss file compile with webpack so it is delivered with the other styles in the node_modules folder.

I have tried to implement this with no luck.  My main scss file is named `styles.global.scss` and I tried to include it with the following rule in my `webpack.config.js` file

```
{ 
    test: /\.global\.scss$/, 
    exclude: /node_modules/, 
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'] 
}
```

I don't get any errors when I run the application and run the webpack command, however, I do not see my styles being applied.  All the resources in my node_modules folder are being applied so at least that works.  I would like to keep view encapsulation on my angular components.  I would prefer to not have to import the main/global scss file into each components scss file as well as having to include it in each of the `stylesUrl` field in the component.ts files.

Please let me know if you need to see any additional code.  Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Wanted to include this in the question in case anyone finds themselves in a similar situation.  I had another rule for .scss files that was directly conflicting with the rule stated above.

```
{ 
   test: /\.scss$/, 
   exclude: /node_modules/, 
   use: [ 'raw-loader', 'sass-loader' ] 
},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you need to just instruct Webpack to process your file. You could do that with an import at the top of `boot.browser.ts` (assuming you're using the standard setup):

```js
import './path/to/styles.global.scss';
```

UPDATE: Based on further discussion in the comments and corresponding chat, we discovered that the two `.scss` rules were conflicting with each other. Based on this, updating the rule shown in the original question fixes the issue:

```js
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: [/node_modules/, /\.global\.scss$/],
    use: [ 'raw-loader', 'sass-loader' ]
}
```

This ensures that `*.global.scss` files are processed only once.